# How does the 'efficiency' of a cyclorotor compare to helicopters and fixed wing aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design

I recently rediscovered the [cyclorotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclorotor) concept. There is a good example on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96DKtu9DFow) here. Ignoring the mechanical complexity to an extent how does the 'efficiency' compare to conventional designs?

When I say efficiency I'm not sure what the best measure is. Possibly lift to drag ratio?
I'm interested in:

- lifting capacity: how much weight could a cyclorotor lift vs a helicopter or fixed wing design
- energy efficiency

Obviously these things depend on factors like size of the airfoil & airspeed so a rough guide would be suffcient.

I also have the same question about aircraft based on the [magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) which I have posted separately.

Comment: One thing is for sure: after more than a century of fligh all together, and the magnus effect, cycloidial rotors and whatnot being of a ripe age also, they are not very efficient when considering practical use. Otherwise they would be used extensively.

Comment: Ask yourself what percentage of the cycle is each wing performing optimally.

Comment: I think part of the challenge for the cyclorotor was partly materials and partly engineering. It clearly works but has not had the same amount of effort put into it.

Comment: "Ask yourself what percentage of the cycle is each wing performing optimally". That is a very good point but presumably it only applies for vertical take ouff, when a blade is not providing lift it can instead contribute thrust in the direction of flight can't it?